# Convert a java.text.DateFormat instance to a strftime string?

Tags: java, date-format, strftime, date-formatting

I've got a `DateFormat` object that I would like to turn into a `strftime` string so I can get consistent date formatting across multiple languages. Is there something in the SDK that I'm missing? If not, is this a feature of some 3rd-party lib that I can grab? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `strftime` translator class in the Apache Tomcat project:

[org.apache.catalina.util.Strftime](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/util/Strftime.html)

Hope that helps.

Comment: That seems to be going the wrong way, sadly. I have a dynamically constructed `DateFormat` object, which I need to keep for doing server-side formatting. What I want is a way to convert that to a `strftime` string so that I can send *that* to the client, where a JavaScript library will perform client-side date-formatting. This seems to let me format a `Date` on the server-side by providing a `strftime` string.